# Why coroutines inherit from IEnumerator?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How does inheriting from **IEnumerator** make the method to behave like a coroutine? This has to be somewhat related to the compiler, right?

```
IEnumerator Fade() 
{
    for (float ft = 1f; ft >= 0; ft -= 0.1f) 
    {
        Color c = renderer.material.color;
        c.a = ft;
        renderer.material.color = c;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unity avoid to let user use `Thread` so as a workaround they use the asynchronisme of an IEnumerator (with `yield`) so user do not block the main thread and can control the execution's frequency of their code

Answer (score 4):

According to [Microsoft's C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator), `IEnumerator` is just a useful interface for iterating through a collection of objects. It defines a `MoveNext()` method and a `Reset()` method for navigating the collection it is attached to. Coroutines can be executed across many frames, so Unity likely uses IEnumerator to iterate across the Coroutine's state changes as each frame progresses.

You can find the declaration of the Coroutine methods in the `MonoBehavior` bindings within Unity's source code [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Scripting/MonoBehaviour.bindings.cs).

Comment: Thanks! I am bad at English, so can you clarify, please, what "Coroutine's state changes" means?

Comment: @PetroKoval In one frame, your `Fade()` coroutine might have the local `ft` variable equal to `0.9`. But in the next frame, it would be equal to `0.8`. The current values of all the variables in the coroutine are called its "state".